# Wordpress - 3 Widgets in a sidebar, Apply "last" class to the third widget

Tags: php, css, widget, wordpress

i've create a custom sidebar in my wordpress site

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Home Widgets',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="blurb %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div> <!-- end .widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

And i've added 3 widgets into it using the widget panel in admin page.

This is the css

`.blurb { float: left; margin-right: 96px; width: 256px; }`

I've also declared a "last" class to remove the margin right to the last (third) widget.

`.last { clear: right; margin-right: 0 !important; }`

How can i apply the "last" class to the last widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to. Change the margin to `margin-left` and make a class `.blurb:first-child {margin-left: 0;}` and you should be fine. IE7+ compatible.

Comment: You use the pseudo class `:first-child` because `:last-child` doesn't have combatibility in IE7 and I believe also 8 but if thats not a problem you could use `:last-child`.

Comment: To clear the children you can change the overflow of the parent to the widgets to something else than auto to make it clear all the widgets in it.